# I can't access Docker container from public IP via port forwarding. Can i check where the request stops?

Tags: docker, portforwarding, plex, openmediavault

I have a debian (10, buster) server with OMV5 with Docker. I have installed Plex as container. He is in the host network. I can access the website with my LAN_IP:32400. If i setup Port forwarding in my router i get message from chrome that **err_connection_unreachable** when i try to access Public_IP:xxxxx. I have the same problem with OMV5. I used "*[https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/*"](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/*%22) to check my ports. They are open. I done port forwarding in the past and it worked (with emby but i didn't used docker)

```
root@HMS:/home/tomas# netstat -tnlp | grep :32400
tcp6       0      0 :::32400                :::*                    LISTEN      31783/Plex Media Se

root@HMS:/home/tomas# lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd       1            root   82u  IPv4    9711      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
systemd       1            root   84u  IPv6    9715      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
rpcbind     543            _rpc    4u  IPv4    9711      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
rpcbind     543            _rpc    6u  IPv6    9715      0t0  TCP *:111 (LISTEN)
systemd-r   545 systemd-resolve   12u  IPv4   17452      0t0  TCP *:5355 (LISTEN)
systemd-r   545 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv6   17455      0t0  TCP *:5355 (LISTEN)
systemd-r   545 systemd-resolve   17u  IPv4   17458      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd        965            root    3u  IPv4   21652      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        965            root    4u  IPv6   21654      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody    7u  IPv6 1586856      0t0  TCP [fe80::cc1d:bf11:ab27:39e9]:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   10u  IPv4 1586885      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.110:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   13u  IPv4   25254      0t0  TCP 172.30.32.1:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   16u  IPv4   23534      0t0  TCP 172.17.0.1:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   19u  IPv6   29730      0t0  TCP [fe80::42:1fff:fef6:e33d]:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   22u  IPv6   27608      0t0  TCP [fe80::42:32ff:feea:4626]:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   25u  IPv4 1322443      0t0  TCP 172.22.0.1:5357 (LISTEN)
python3    1040          nobody   28u  IPv6 1326814      0t0  TCP [fe80::42:40ff:fe86:b55c]:5357 (LISTEN)
smbd       1205            root   30u  IPv6   23693      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
smbd       1205            root   31u  IPv6   23694      0t0  TCP *:139 (LISTEN)
smbd       1205            root   32u  IPv4   23695      0t0  TCP *:445 (LISTEN)
smbd       1205            root   33u  IPv4   23696      0t0  TCP *:139 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  1509            root    4u  IPv4   24163      0t0  TCP *:4357 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  1514            root    4u  IPv4   24167      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  1534            root    4u  IPv4   26950      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
nginx      5631            root    6u  IPv4   40960      0t0  TCP 172.30.32.1:62452 (LISTEN)
nginx      5686            root    6u  IPv4   40960      0t0  TCP 172.30.32.1:62452 (LISTEN)
nginx      6460            root    8u  IPv6 1293937      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      6461        www-data    8u  IPv6 1293937      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      6462        www-data    8u  IPv6 1293937      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      6463        www-data    8u  IPv6 1293937      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      6464        www-data    8u  IPv6 1293937      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
proftpd   16027         proftpd    0u  IPv6  732740      0t0  TCP *:21 (LISTEN)
python3   21014            root    7u  IPv6 1595813      0t0  TCP *:8123 (LISTEN)
python3   21014            root    8u  IPv4 1595814      0t0  TCP *:8123 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20M 31783           admin   60u  IPv6 2080116      0t0  TCP *:32400 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20M 31783           admin   61u  IPv4 2080118      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:32401 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20S 31812           admin    7u  IPv4 2080149      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:35321 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20D 31857           admin   14u  IPv4 2080894      0t0  TCP *:1238 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20D 31857           admin   29u  IPv4 2080907      0t0  TCP *:32469 (LISTEN)
Plex\x20T 31861           admin   13u  IPv4 2080174      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:32600 (LISTEN)
```

***I believe that the problem is between server pc and the docker. But why it then works over LAN?***

Thank you.

Comment: i don't know if it matters, but i have also other containers installed homeassistant (it has 7 containers total). I can't port forward to it either. But locally it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem was hairpinning. My router doesn't support it.